# Running DB2 SQL from shell command line does not finishing execution

Tags: sql, bash, shell, db2, remote-access

I am on a unix server which is set up to remotely connect to another db2 unix server.
I was able to connect to DB2 using following script:

```
db2 "connect to <server name> user <user name> using <pass>";
```

Then I ran following command to save results of SQL to a file

```
db2 "select * from <tablename>" > /myfile.txt
```

The script starts execution but never ends.I tried using `-x` before select too but same result never ends execution.Table is small has only one record.When I forcefully end execution the header of table gets saved in file with following error:

```
SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.  SQLSTATE=57014
```

Please help I am stuck in a riddle.

Comment: Sounds a bit like something is locking that table. An uncommitted transaction maybe?

Comment: Perhaps this is just a really big table and is overwhelming the system with lots of data.  Try putting a `fetch first 10 rows only` clause on the query to see if it returns more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could monitor the connection and the output file in order to know what is happening.

Before start the monitoring, get the current application handle

```
db2 "values SYSPROC.MON_GET_APPLICATION_ID()"
```

- Open a second terminal, and execute db2top against your databases. Checks the current sessions (L) and take a look at your connection (previous application ID). If you see a Lock Wait status, it is just because another connection put a lock on that table, and it is not possible to read it concurrently.

  db2top -d myDB

Try to execute the same query with another isolation level

```
db2 "select * from <tablename> WITH UR"
```

If that is the problem, you should analyze which other processes are running (modifying data) on the database.

- Open another terminal, and do a

  tail -f /myfile.txt

If you see the file is changing, it is just because the output is too big. Just wait.

Comment: will that work if table has exclusive lock acquired by some query? I think answer is no, correct me if wrong.

Comment: If your query is in 'lock waiting' and the 'lock timeout' is infinitive (-1), your query will be hold until the application that hold the lock release it.

Comment: When using WITH UR in a query, it does not take into account the locks on the rows, however the results could not be exact (phantom reads, etc.)